# How to update Tomcat on Centos 6.3?

Tags: centos, tomcat, centos6, tomcat6

I'm running CentOS release 6.3 (Final) and I have Tomcat 6.0.24 installed:

```
# yum info tomcat6
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: dallas.tx.mirror.xygenhosting.com
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: mirror.steadfast.net
 * updates: mirrors.gigenet.com
Installed Packages
Name        : tomcat6
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 6.0.24
Release     : 45.el6
Size        : 188 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
```

Current Tomcat 6 release is now 6.0.35. `yum update` is not updating my Tomcat installation, though.

1. How can I find out if there is an updated Centos 6 package for Tomcat 6?
2. How can I update it?
3. Should I add a different repository to make sure I receive Tomcat updates?

Comment: http://www.jpackage.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your yum info command is the best way to see what version is in the Centos repos.
2. Just because there is a  Tomcat update may not mean there is one available in the repos. It will need to be added to the repo first before you can update it.
3. You could see about adding Centos-Fasttrack or Testing repos, however it will update everything it has available. So if you just want to keep tomcat up to date you may want to search the repos http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.3/ or get the binary straight from Apache http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi

Overall it may be best to wait until it is in the Centos Repo. Building from the source or binary means you are on the bleeding edge and an issue may creep up for your distro.

Comment: Thank you. So it seems the most recent version in the official repo is 6.0.24, which is 2.5 years and 7 minor releases out-of-date. I seem to be missing a lot of error corrections, stability improvements and security patches by using the official CentOS repo. On the other hand, switching to the Fasttrack repo would have a global effect. I suppose the best route is to ignore the official package and install (and update) Tomcat manually.

Comment: You hit it on the head. Remember by updating it manually you may not be able to update it again via yum. All depends on how the new version gets installed etc.

Comment: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.3 is deprecated, now it's: /http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/